# Как правильно написать "Приказ о перенесении отпуска"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать "Приказ о перенесении отпуска"?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то пишут "о переносе". Вот образец: http://www.bddo.ru/dog_60_75.htm

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема? Все правильно написано.
Далее, как обычно: шапка, дальше "Приказываю перенести...".
Так что у Вас все правильно